# SimpleXML in PHP Loop

Tags: php, xml

im trying to loop through some XML data using PHP. Currently it just only brings back one, but i want it to bring back all the data.

```
<?php
$request_url = "http://finlay.tumblr.com/api/read";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
$title = $xml->posts->post->{'regular-title'};
$post = $xml->posts->post->{'regular-body'};
$link = $xml->posts->post['url'];
$small_post = substr($post,0,320);
echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
echo '<p>'.$small_post.'</p>';
echo "...";
echo "</br><a target=frame2 href='".$link."'>Read More</a>"; 
?>
```

Comment: Be careful, if the xml is large, you may want to look into XMLReader (http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php), not as easy to use but will be far less of a memory footprint.

Answer (score 1):

```
$request_url = "http://finlay.tumblr.com/api/read";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($request_url);
foreach($xml->posts->post as $post)
{
    $title = $post->{'regular-title'};
    $post = $post->{'regular-body'};
    $link = $post['url'];
    $small_post = substr($post,0,320);
    echo '<h1>'.$title.'</h1>';
    echo '<p>'.$small_post.'</p>';
    echo "...";
    echo "</br><a target=frame2 href='".$link."'>Read More</a>"; 
}
```